# How to calculate the age from y/m/d with carbon?

Tags: php, php-carbon

So I have a date, lets say `720402`. And the format is year (72), month (04) and day (02). And I want to be able to output the age from this string with carbon. And Carbon has this age function

`$howOldAmI = Carbon::createFromDate(1975, 5, 21)->age;` But I cannot convert my current format to the correct one, for carbon to use.

Comment: Make a function to convert the date to an accepted carbon format.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Carbon::createFromFormat()` instead to parse your date, i.e.:

```
$howOldAmI = Carbon::createFromFormat("ymd", "720402")->age;  // 46
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a date like this( $date = '1999-12-20') format you can use

$howOldAmI = Carbon::parse($date)->age;  instead of Carbon::createFromDate(1975, 5, 21)->age;

also you can monitor https://www.nicesnippets.com/blog/laravel-carbon-calculate-age